# How to implement Javascript's XmlHttpRequest in C#?

Tags: c#, web-services

There is an [old article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/hr-hr/magazine/cc301587%28en-us%29.aspx) in the MSDN Magazine with a walk-through to implement in C# the equivalent of the Javascript XMLHttpRequest object.

I find it very interesting but the code is not downloadable anymore.

**Do you know of an implementation similar to the Javascript XMLHttpRequest object but in C#?**
Among other thinks, this implementation can:

- Send http requests to the server.
- Send requests both synchronously and asynchronously.
- Allows to abort long running processes.

I know it all can be done easily with the HTTPWebRequest object in .NET, but after reading the article I was hoping that a wrapper would be available as it used to be in the code of that article (the link is dead).

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [WebClient Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [WebClient.DownloadString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstring.aspx) that is a good wrapper around a web request. You can have a non blocking call too ( the better way ) by using [DownloadStringAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144202.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use WebClient, though I often find it wraps a bit too much and I end up going back to HTTPWebRequest.

There's plenty of the code from that article in it's figures at http://msdn.microsoft.com/hr-hr/magazine/bb985675%28en-us%29.aspx Enough really to reconstruct the whole thing.